# amlogic tools 5.5.0 application error, giving error application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b) fix

Tags: windows

I want to change my stb rom, but when I run amlogic tools it shows error, application was unable to start correctly (`0xc00007b`) with `amlogic tools 5.5.0`.

I tried using other versions also but same error coming.